# One-time password authentication for NodeJS Express web application

Tags: node.js, passwords, passport.js, one-time-password

I have a NodeJS Express application with Passport.js email and password authentication. Users either reuse passwords from other websites or fail to remember them, so I want to do away with user passwords entirely.

I want to implement one-time passwords by email or text message. When a user signs up or logs in, they would receive by email or text message a 4-digit code. Adding that  which authenticates them and places a cookie for a persistent session. The Passport docs support password and OAuth authentication but I could not find a one-time password strategy.

I could implement it by changing the password validation method and I wonder if it already exists out-of-the-box. Does Passport or another NodeJS library implement one-time password authentication?

Comment: For what it's worth, the one-time password you propose to send your user is a kind of API Key.  There's an api key strategy for passport here. http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-localapikey/  But be careful: four-digit codes are remarkably vulnerable to brute force guessing.

Comment: You might want tot refer https://www.npmjs.com/package/otplib

Comment: @O.Jones I see: I can use the Local API key strategy with a user method that authenticates this token, maybe using `otplib`. In fact, I could even keep the current password strategy and ask the user to enter that token in the password field. Thanks for the tip on 4-digit codes, would you like to write an answer?